# Security at writing in a folder

Tags: java, permissions

I would like to run with Runtime.exec() programs in Java (the programs' code are in C and Java ) - the users are uploading the Java/C code, and my app runs them. The code is saved in a separate folder for each user, as well as the input and output files.

In case of C code, the compilation code is the following:

```
compileCommand = pathToMinGW + "gcc " + pathToFile + fileName + ".c -o " + pathToFile + fileName
```

And the command for run:

```
executeCommand = pathToFile + fileName + ".exe"
```

Running the command:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process run = runtime.exec(executeCommand);
```

How can I give permissions for the exec() function, to let to modify the output files from the folder where the uploaded code is, but nothing other?

Comment: Depends what OS you are using and from what user you need to run the main java. Basically in linux, you can make a folder, from which all exe files including java will not have any other permission than granted, in windows, you need to setup a user, isolate it (like no groups), and run it from that, but for this, your main java needs to be run from administrator account. Also, you can introduce 3rd service which runs only exe files from unprivileged users. You would need also to run exe after exe (serialize it), so they dont interfere with each other.

Comment: ps. A separate service running from administrator, which can execute programs from unprivileged users, one by one, so they dont interfere, just running, no compiling  etc. For this, create account on 2008 R2 or 7, remove it from all groups, and grant any other file system permission needed, e.g. read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an isolated user first (e.g. with no groups on it),and you run another java instance from administrator (via windows service for example), were you push the commands in a queue, and you got a queue of error codes, in e.g. SQL DB.

And in Linux, you can run also Java from root, and make a queue of commands (with files in folder and SQL, and push the commands and receive the results via another queue).

And the Java instance running exe must run from root or administrator, to be able to run another exe with different user, so you dont need to reload java every time. In windows you would need to compile a binary doing this using windows Process, to launch external command via another user. In Linux you can use "su" or "sudo" commands to do it, so you can do:

```
[root@abcdef ~]# su - test -c "/usr/bin/id"
uid=503(test) gid=503(test) groups=503(test) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

So your java would require access to the SQL with the queue, so this would be the easier way I suppose, I have did this way and I am so far not hacked.

ps. Queue has to be serialized and with timeout for each run.